# Build a sorted dojo digit tree from XmlStore

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree, xmlstore

Is it possible to create a sorted tree in DOJO using digit tree from XmlStore?  The data in the XML is not always guaranteed to be sorted.

If it is possible, please help me with some pointers.